# Google People API - What do I need to access an individual user's contacts from a service account?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-workspace, google-api-dotnet-client

I am writing an app (C#/Windows) that takes data from another source and uses it to keep Google mailing lists and contact information up-to-date for a particular user in my domain.  I've got it to the point that I'm able to read the members of all of the Google email groups, so I've got the basics working, but now I'm running into a roadblock trying to read & update information for the contacts the user has defined.

I'm using OAuth2 and have a service account created, and in the domain-wide delegation
screen I've added "auth/contacts" permissions to my service account (and I think to my app, though I can't now find what that client ID maps to).

[image: API Clients]
When I run this code:

```
credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
   GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
   new[] { PeopleServiceService.Scope.DirectoryReadonly, PeopleServiceService.Scope.Contacts },
   "[snip]@email-group-updater.iam.gserviceaccount.com", CancellationToken.None);
var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
   { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = "UpdateMailGroups" };
var people_service = new PeopleServiceService(initializer);
var pc = people_service.People.Connections.List("people/me");
var x = pc.Execute();
```

it throws the exception

```
GoogleApiException: The service people has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
Error=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]
Errors [
    Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]

ErrorResponseContent={
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "people.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.people.v1.PeopleService.ListConnections"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I have never been able to find documentation that say "if you want resource X, you need authentication scope Y".

In this case, what authentication am I missing?

EDIT

I created a key for my service account and downloaded the file to my machine, per Linda's suggestion I changed the code to be

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(serviceAccountKeyjsonFile)
   .CreateScoped(new[] { PeopleServiceService.Scope.DirectoryReadonly})
   .CreateWithUser(<user I'm impersonating>);
```

That function succeeds and gives me an OAuth2.GoogleCredential object, but when I call People.Connections.List.Execute() it throws an exception:

```
Exception: Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.", Uri:""
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont apear to be using the code for a service account.

```
   var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(PathToServiceAccountKeyFile)
            .CreateScoped(Scopes)
            .CreateWithUser(userToImpersonate);


var service = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Daimto Testing Workspace with service account"
            }
        );
```

Make sure to set userToImpersonate to the user who you want the service account to impersonate.

The scope you need is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts
```

which should be something like (kinda guessing on the actual name )

```
private static readonly string[] Scopes = {PeopleServiceService.Scope.Contacts};
```

Comment: It tells me "InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: Error creating credential from JSON or JSON parameters. Unrecognized credential type ."  Is the "service account key file" this file I downloaded named client_secret_[snip].apps.googleusercontent.com.json?

Comment: On the "IAM&Admin/Service accounts" page, it lists my service account, but in the "Key ID" column it says "No keys".  When I click on key management, it says "We recommend you avoid downloading service account keys and instead use the Workload Identity Federation"

Comment: Please see "EDIT" above

Comment: Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asrCdWFrF0A

Comment: That YouTube video is for Google Cloud Platform, I've got a C#/Windows application

Comment: That video shows you how to create a service account that can be used to access Google apis of which the people api is one.   Yes with C# from an installed application.   It is not a google cloud service account these are two different systems.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("credentials.json")
            .CreateScoped(Scopes)
            .CreateWithUser("erwin@contoso.nl")
            .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
```